# Angular 5 - loader service not working.

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular5

I need to create a service for my Angular 5 application that will show a loader while the router is loading a page. This is what I came up with so far :

```
@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {
public loaderShown$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); 

constructor(public router: Router, private ngZone: NgZone, public logger: LoggerService) {
    router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
        this.interceptNavigation(event)
    })
}

public toggle(visible: boolean) {
    //this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        console.log('toggled ' + visible);
        this.loaderShown$.next(visible);
   //});
}

private interceptNavigation(event: RouterEvent) {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.toggle(true);           
    }

    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.toggle(false); 
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
        this.toggle(false);
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
        this.toggle(false);
    }
} 
}
```

And in the app.component I'm subscribing the service :

```
this.loaderService.loaderShown$.subscribe(shown => {
    this.loaderShown = shown; 
  }, (err) => console.log(err));
```

It works like a charm. However, when I try to call the toggle method of the LoaderService in a component, it doesn't do anything  - the value is not broadcasting. It looks like the subscription was cancelled. But when I navigate to another page it works again (which is strange). Do you know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have your `LoaderService` provided more than once? (meaning is it in more than one module's `providers` array?)

Comment: Have you been able to place breakpoints in your javascript (from web browser) to trace the flow of actions based on your logic? Also it is important to synchronize between when you toggle show/hide such that there is sufficient time for you to view the loading, otherwise the loader is shown and hidden almost instantly without you noticing that.

Comment: No, it's only defined in one module. I also did debug the application. When I call the toggle method on the service it gets called but the subscription in the app.component is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Angular not treating service as a singleton in my lazy-loaded structure. I've been able to resolve this with updating te module in which the service resides and then defining it as forRoot() in the AppModule. This ensured tat the service is a singleton.